# Converting NSData to Integer in Swift

Tags: swift, integer, nsdata

In Objective-C the code looked liked this and worked flawlessly,

```
NSInteger random = arc4random_uniform(99) + 1 
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:& random length: sizeof(random)];
int value = *(int*)([data bytes]);
```

How can this be done in Swift?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Like this:

```
var src: NSInteger = 2525
var out: NSInteger = 0

let data = NSData(bytes: &src, length: sizeof(NSInteger))
data.getBytes(&out, length: sizeof(NSInteger))
println(out) // ==> 2525
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect! Thank you!

Comment: or `sizeofValue(random)`

Comment: In Swift3: sizeof(NSInteger) becomes MemoryLayout<NSInteger>.size and println becomes print.

Comment: Note that for getting the size directly from the type not the object in Swift 3 or later version of `sizeofValue ` is `MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: value)`

Answer (score 10):

## **In Swift 4:**

There are a couple of things to consider when extracting an integer value from a `Data` stream. *Signedness* and *Endianess*. So I came up with a function in an extension to `Data` that infers *Signedness* from the type of integer you want to extract and passes *Endianess* and `Index` as parameters. The types of integers that can be extracted are all that conform to `FixedWidthInteger` protocol.

**Reminder:** This function will not check if the `Index` range is inside the bounds of the `Data` buffer so it may crash depending on the size of the type being extracted in relation to the end of the buffer.

```swift
extension Data {
    enum Endianness {
        case BigEndian
        case LittleEndian
    }
    func scanValue<T: FixedWidthInteger>(at index: Data.Index, endianess: Endianness) -> T {
        let number: T = self.subdata(in: index..<index + MemoryLayout<T>.size).withUnsafeBytes({ $0.pointee })
        switch endianess {
        case .BigEndian:
            return number.bigEndian
        case .LittleEndian:
            return number.littleEndian
        }
    }
}
```

**Example:**

```
let data = Data(bytes: [0xFF,0x1F,0x1F,0xFF])

let number1 = data.scanValue(at: 0, endianess: .LittleEndian) as UInt16
let number2 = data.scanValue(at: 0, endianess: .BigEndian) as UInt16

let number3: Int16 = data.scanValue(at: 2, endianess: .LittleEndian)
let number4: Int16 = data.scanValue(at: 2, endianess: .BigEndian)
```

**Results:**

`number1 is 8191`
`number2 is 65311`
`number3 is -225`
`number4 is 8191`

Observe the function calls to see how the type to be extracted is inferred. Of course *Endianess* doesn't make sense for `Int8` or `UInt8`, but the function works as expected.

Values can later be cast to `Int` if needed.

Comment: Hi - Have u got a much simpler solution for just converting data <02> to UInt8 2 or Int 2?

Comment: @richc: The simplest way to get a `UInt8` is to simply use a subscript if you know exactly the index of the byte you want: `data[index]`

Comment: `Data.Index` inside a `Data` extension is redundant. Use just `Index`

Comment: I think you should be using `MemoryLayout`.`stride` - not `size`. See the docs for `stride`, which define it as "The number of bytes from the start of one instance of T to the start of the next when stored in contiguous memory or in an Array<T>" and "the number of bytes moved when an UnsafePointer<T> instance is incremented"

Answer (score 7):

You can extend Data type, create a generic method, get the bytes and cast it or set the resulting type explicitly as needed:

```
extension Data {
    func object<T>(at index: Index = 0) -> T {
        subdata(in: index..<self.index(index, offsetBy: MemoryLayout<T>.size))
        .withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(as: T.self) }
    }
}
```

---

```
extension Numeric {
    var data: Data {
        var source = self
        return Data(bytes: &source, count: MemoryLayout<Self>.size)
    }
}
```

---

```
let data = Data([0xFF, 0x1F])   // 2 bytes

let uint16: UInt16 = data.object()      // 8191  littleEndian
let number1 = uint16.littleEndian       // 8191
let number2 = uint16.bigEndian          // 65311

let int16 = data.object() as Int16      // 8191   littleEndian
let number3 = int16.littleEndian        // 8191
let number4 = int16.bigEndian           // -225

print(number1) // 8191
print(number2) // 65311
print(number3) // 8191
print(number4) // -225
```

---

Testing with `Int`

```
let random = Int.random(in: 1...100)    // 15 UInt32
let data = random.data                  // 8 bytes  [15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Testing with `UInt32`

```
let random = UInt32.random(in: 1...100)  // 90 UInt32
let data = random.data                   // 4 bytes  [90, 0, 0, 0]
```

Testing with Double

```
let random = Double.random(in: 0...1)  // 0.2463145485351322 Double
let data = random.data                 // 8 bytes  [12, 99, 62, 49, 60, 135, 207, 63]
```

If you want to extract a subdata:

```
let data = Data([0xFF, 0x1F, 0x1F, 0xFF])      // 4 bytes

let uint16: UInt16 = data.object(at: 2)        //  65311 littleEndian
let number1 = uint16.littleEndian              // 65311
let number2 = uint16.bigEndian                 // 8191

let int16: Int16 = data.object(at: 2)          // -225   littleEndian
let number3 = int16.littleEndian               // -225
let number4 = int16.bigEndian                  // 8191

number1 // 65311
number2 // 8191
number3 // -225
number4 // 8191
```

Answer (score 6):

For Swift 3, you can do this (little endian, but similar for big):

```
func getInt(fromData data: Data, start: Int) -> Int32 {
  let intBits = data.withUnsafeBytes({(bytePointer: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) -> Int32 in
    bytePointer.advanced(by: start).withMemoryRebound(to: Int32.self, capacity: 4) { pointer in
      return pointer.pointee
    }
  })
  return Int32(littleEndian: intBits)
}
```

You can modify this, add generics, etc. to fit other primitive types (and vary it depending on the endianness of the data bytes).

Comment: This is really the thing that irks me a bit about Swift. This is extremely complicated things for something that is technically extremely simple. I wonder if the compiler optimises all the bs away

Answer (score 5):

You might find this method useful if you are doing it a lot:

```
func readInteger<T : IntegerType>(data : NSData, start : Int) -> T {
    var d : T = 0
    data.getBytes(&d, range: NSRange(location: start, length: sizeof(T)))
    return d
}
```

The function takes as a parameter the start position in the data to read the numeric type and it returns a value of the a type inferred from whatever you are assigning it to.

For example:

```
let i : UInt32 = readInteger(data, 10);
```

reads an 4 byte integer from position 10 in the data.

If you change `UInt32` to `UInt16` it will read two bytes.

Comment: please elaborate some more on how to use it and what are the parameters to pass... thank you.

Answer (score 1):

My contribution with a swift 3.1 extension :

```
extension NSData{
    var int :  Int{
        var out: Int = 0
        self.getBytes(&out, length: MemoryLayout<Int>.size)
        return out
    }
}
```

Just call .int to get your value, just like this :

```
let value = 50
let data = NSData(bytes: &value, length: 4)
print(data.int)
```

Answer (score 0):

Data to interger thanks @rghome

```
// MARK: - Extensions Data

extension Data {

    /// To interger Data by range
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - data:       Data
    ///   - startRange: StartRange
    ///   - endRange:   EndRange
    /// - Returns:      Integer Typed
    func toInterger<T : Integer>(withData data: NSData, withStartRange startRange: Int, withSizeRange endRange: Int) -> T {
        var d : T = 0
        (self as NSData).getBytes(&d, range: NSRange(location: startRange, length: endRange))
        return d
    }
}

101010
let value:Int = Data().toInterger(withStartRange: 0, withEndRange: 2)
get 10
get 2 Int
```