# Convert each Byte of NSData to equivalent Int Value

Tags: swift

I have an NSData object that is being allocated with bytes that are representing unsigned integers from 0-255. What is the simplest way to convert these bytes to integers, or, if it is easier, to a string/NSString?

For instance, if I have bytes 0x00, 0x02, and 0x0A in my NSData object, then I would like to have either an integer array of {0,2,10} or the string/NSString "0210".

It seems that there are plenty of ways to turn NSData into ASCII NSStrings,UInt8 arrays, etc, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this simple conversion in Swift.

Edit: Example Code of what I want:

```
var data:NSData
/*allocate NSData*/
var unsignedInts = [Int]()
/*Allocate each byte of data to an individual index of unsignedInts */
print(unsignedInts)
//should see {0, 1, 10} if bytes are 0x00, 0x01, and 0x0A
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting NSData to Integer in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26227702/converting-nsdata-to-integer-in-swift)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is necessary to create a new Array of Int because Int require more bytes per entry.

```
var nsData: NSData = NSData(bytes: [0x00, 0x02, 0x0A] as [UInt8], length: 3)
let buffer = UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>(start:UnsafePointer<UInt8>(nsData.bytes), count:nsData.length)
print("nsData: \(nsData)")

var intData = [Int]()
intData.reserveCapacity(nsData.length)

var stringData = String()

for i in 0..<nsData.length {
    intData.append(Int(buffer[i]))
    stringData += String(buffer[i])
}

print("intData: \(intData)")
print("stringData: \(stringData)")
```

nsData: <00020a>
intData: [0, 2, 10]
stringData: 0210

Comment: Thanks for your time @zaph, much appreciated.

Comment: This isn't very efficient, as the `intArray` and `stringData` has to allocate new memory a lot.. You should use `reserveCapacity` to avoid that

Comment: @zaph Better, but `reserveCapacity` doesn't take the amount of bytes, but rather the amount of elements (the `sizeof`s aren't needed). Also the string actually needs about 2-3 times more elements, as the string of a `UInt8` can range from "0" (1 char) to "256" (3 chars), a factor of 3 should do. If you want the math: 10/256 prob of 1 char, 90/256 prob of 2 chars, 156/256 prob of 3 chars gives a factor of about 2.57 (assuming a random distribution), which would give `stringData.reserveCapacity(Int(Double(nsData.length) * 2.57))`). Of course this is just a detail, `append` isn't that bad anyways

Comment: @Kametrixom thanks for the information and yes, I totally missed considering the size needed for a string representation of a byte. I have removed the `reserveCapacity` for the string as it affods minimmal improvement (< 1us) and adds complexity.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend a method like this:

```
import Foundation

extension NSData {
    var byteBuffer : UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<UInt8> {
        return UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: UnsafeMutablePointer(bytes), count: length)
    }

    var array : [UInt8] {
        return Array(byteBuffer)
    }

    var intArray : [Int] {
        return byteBuffer.map(Int.init)
    }

    var byteString : String {
        return byteBuffer.lazy.map(String.init).joinWithSeparator("")
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let data1 = NSData(bytes: [0x48, 0xa1, 0x95, 0xe, 0x1c, 0x38, 0x82] as [UInt8], length: 7)       // <48a1950e 1c3882>

print(data1.array)       // "[72, 161, 149, 14, 28, 56, 130]"
print(data1.intArray)    // "[72, 161, 149, 14, 28, 56, 130]"
print(data1.byteString)  // "72161149142856130"

let data2 = NSData(bytes: [0x00, 0x02, 0x0A] as [UInt8], length: 3)

print(data2.array)       // "[0, 2, 10]"
print(data2.intArray)    // "[0, 2, 10]"
print(data2.byteString)  // "0210"
```

It's very easy, Swift-y and efficient like this.

Note that in some cases you don't actually need an array like this, because you can just access all the values of the data in the same way without allocating a new array (recommended):

```
data1.byteBuffer[4]      // 28
data1.byteBuffer.count   // 7
data1.byteBuffer(14)     // 3
```

EDIT: I added a property that returns an `Int` array, although I can't see a reason you'd need it

Comment: @zaph I edited my answer, although that's not really a reason to downvote imho

Comment: @zaph btw have a look at what it says when you hover over the downvote button: "This answer is not useful"   ->  Downvotes aren't for answers that don't 100% answer the original question

Comment: It does seem you have a really good grasp of Swift and the answer provides a correct answer but I disagree with the solution. IMO the solution is horrible.

Comment: @zaph Why do you disagree? I just chose the more functional way (in Swift's spirit) of doing it and you chose the imperative way

Comment: If you want to chat about why let me know.

Comment: I'll give you some idea of there I am coming from: Write the clearest code possible for the next developer. Name things carefully with very descriptive names. Kent Beck *Do The Simplest Thing That Could Possibly Work*. Brian Kernighan: *Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92907/discussion-between-kametrixom-and-zaph).