# Convert BLE 4.0 data into usable information using Swift (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

This is my first BLE project using swift and would greatly appreciate any direction you guys have out there. My arduino is using a red bear lab BLE mini to send integers (between 1 and 1200) from a sensor to my iPhone app. I am able to find and connect to the device and transfer the data. I, at least for the past three days, cannot figure how to convert that data back to usable information.

For example in the didUpdateValueForCharacteristic function if I print:

```
print(characteristic.value!.bytes)
```

I get a return that looks like:

```
0x000000013cdb5f80
```

If I were to print characteristic.value! I would get something that looked like:

```
<hc>
```

It seems that I've read everything on the internet about this and still cannot figure out how to get this reading back to the integer being sent. It would be greatly appreciated if someone would be willing to give me some guidance here.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: Based on the feedback I'm posting some code that I've used but is not returning what I need. I've attempted to turn the value into an integer using the following:

```
            var out : NSInteger = 0
            let data = NSData(bytes: characteristic.value!.bytes, length: sizeof(NSInteger))
            data.getBytes(&out, length: sizeof(NSInteger))
            print("Integer: \(out)")
```

This returns the integer 64816. I'm expecting a number between 0 and 1200 so this is either wrong or I'm missing a step.

I've also attempted to turn the data into a string using:

```
            var string1 = NSString(data: characteristic.value!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
            print("String: \(string1)")
```

This just unwraps a nil value and crashes.

Comment: `characteristic.value` is a `NSData` object. Look how to transform `NSData` to `Integer`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26227702/converting-nsdata-to-integer-in-swift

Comment: Thanks Larme for your comment. I've attempted to turn the NSData into an integer and posted the code I'm using above. It converts the NSData object into an integer of 64816. I'm expecting a much lower number... Do you know if I'm missing a step or doing something wrong? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after three days of struggling I figured this out. Answer had nothing to do with the swift code. Instead my baud rate on the arduino was too slow. Increasing this solved everything.

Answer (score 0):

First confirm they type of object being returned. The value property is of NSData type, so you can use the following code to convert it to NSString.

```
- (id)initWithData:(NSData *)data encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
```

Comment: Thanks Ujjwal for the help. I'm using swift so my code's a little different but I have tried your suggestion. However whenever I do this it unwraps a nil value and the app crashes. I've posed the code I'm using in the above post. Have you got any ideas on steps I'm missing? Thanks for the help.